# jquery delegate syntax .each()

Tags: jquery, delegates

I'm having trouble getting the syntax write for an $.each equivalent using delegates.

All the examples I've read just show click or hover but how would I go about writing this  with the delegate syntax?

```
$("ul li a").each(function(){

    $(this).addClass("foo");

});
```

Cheers!!

Edit: Following the multitude of comments (thanks by the way) I thought I'd better post a more explicit example. My apologies for the lack of detail in my prior question.

Say for example I want to bind tooltips to anchors on a page. I'll have a lot of items that I want to set up as tips and I want to reduce the memory overhead by using delegation.

As I understand this is how I would get started:

```
$(document).delegate("a.tooltip", "click", function(event){

// run click event

}).delegate("a.tooltip", "hover", function(event){

// run mousenter, mouseleave events.

});
```

But lets say for each of those anchors I want to remove the title attribute so it doesn't show up in the browser when I hover. I would imagine (I am guessing here though) that any native events like that would run before my hover event so I want to remove it before I hover over.

Normally I would use something like this:

```
$("a.tooltip").each(function () {
    // Store our title attribute and remove it so we don't get browser 
    //tooltips showing up.
    $.prop(this, "data-old-title", $.attr(this, "title"));
}).removeAttr("title");
```

Can this be done a better way?

From what I understand in the comments and answers delegate covers events only and I will still have to keep anything like this separate.

Comment: Did you mean to use `live` instead of `addClass`? Are you talking about these delegates?: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: `each` and `delegate` are two different things. What do you want to do?

Comment: @Felix Kling : written [here](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) `Delegate` is an alternative to using the `.live()`method, allowing for each binding of event delegation to specific DOM elements.

Comment: @diEcho: I know `live` and `delegate`. But `each` has a different purpose than those, that's why I don't see how it should be substituted with `delegate`.

Comment: `delegate` is for event handling. `each` is for iterating over a set of elements and perform some action *now*. Given that it does not make sense to exchange them. You have to provide more information. What should be the result?

Comment: @Felix: Maybe the OP is confused about the example on the doc.  How it shows [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) being used instead of `each` and `live`.

Comment: @Rocket: Ah I see now... I still think the question needs clarification.

Comment: @Felix kling; i m completely agree with u. i m also not confident enough to write the answer without knowing the exact situtaions

Comment: @All: I've added more info to the question. I fear now though that it may have been a stupid one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have a misconception of what [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is or how it works. It's **not** some kind of magic function which intercepts all DOM manipulations, it just takes advantage of the event bubbling feature of the DOM, hence it can only be used for events.

Basically if you have a `<div>` element, to which you intend to add a `<button>` later, you can use `.delegate()` to bind the click event to the `<div>` itself.

In the future, when you **do** add your button, clicking it will fire the click event of the button, and it will carry on bubbling up the DOM, calling each parent element's click event in succession, until it reaches the document root or one of the handlers call `event.stopPropagation()`. At one point, it will reach your `<div>`, where you've bound your delegate event. The delegate event will check if the element that originally fired the event matches the original selector (to which you wanted to bind your event in the first place), and if it does, it fires the attached event handler **in the context of** your button, so within the event handler **it will look like** the button threw the event.

As you see there is no magic, it has nothing to do with monitoring the DOM for changes or anything like that. If you want to add special classes as you add elements to the DOM, you have to make sure you call a function yourself whenever that happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul").delegate("a", "hover", function(){
    $(this).addClass("hover");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no jQuery for `.delegate()` that would be equivalent to `.each()`

Delegate allows you to attach event handlers to objects that exist now or in the future.

Each allows you to loop through a collection of objects

If you wanted to add class `foo` to the anchor tag based off of some event then you could do something like:

```
$('ul li').delegate('a', 'click', function(){
    $(this).addClass("foo");
});
```

Comment: @diEcho Any part in particular?